# Excel Vlookup a total that equals to the sum of some rows in an array

Tags: excel, sum, vlookup

[2 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNbFd.png)

**day   |product|           detail amount**

Sunday| water|          9

Sunday| mango   |        10

Sunday| onion|          15

Sunday| cocacola|   3

Sunday| tomato|         14

---

**day|  place|          total amount**

Sunday| grocery|    39

Sunday| supermarket|    12

---

**i want the result**

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9hoI.png)

**day|  product|      detail amount|              place**

Sunday| water|    9|                      supermarket

Sunday| mango|    10|                     grocery

Sunday| onion|    15|                     grocery

Sunday  cocacola  3                   supermarket

Sunday  tomato    14                      grocery

**the logic of it is to**

1.only on sunday

2.serach for the numbers in details table that will match totals table

3.the 2 tables are always equal in grand total

Comment: How is the formula meant to decide which of the potential combinations to choose if there is more than one possible solution? What would the logic be then?

Comment: This would not be possible with just formulas. May be VBA. But as @Jorvik77 said, if there are multiple possibilities, there is a chance for the script to return the unexpected value

Comment: As there will be an element of recursion/trial and error, it really doesn't suit formulas.  I think you could do it with n columns where n is every possible permutation (count(places)^count(rows)).. but that would be prohibitively complicated and would not scale at all.  As others have said, find the correct answer is impossible, so would be much better to record where something was bought from when it's bought!